# Datagridview not changing image in cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I am working with DataGridViewObject in my Windows form, using VB.NET. I have three columns that need to display icons. But, based on some info from row, that icons will be shown or not. My problem is that image won't change when I change its value. Basically, I define my columns like this:

```
Dim column1 As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn()
column1.Image = My.Resources.image1
column1.Width = 30
dw.Columns.Add(column1)

Dim column2 As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn()
column2.Image = My.Resources.image2
column2.Width = 30
dw.Columns.Add(column2)

Dim column3 As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn()
column3.Image = My.Resources.image3
column3.Width = 30
dw.Columns.Add(column3)
```

After the data is filled, I am looping through rows, and if I do not want to show the images in that row, I do:

```
Dim cell1 As DataGridViewImageCell = row.Cells(9)
Dim cell2 As DataGridViewImageCell = row.Cells(10)
Dim cell3 As DataGridViewImageCell = row.Cells(11)

cell1.Value = Nothing
cell2.Value = Nothing
cell3.Value = Nothing
```

But, my images stay. Anyone knows what am I missing?

Comment: Is the DGV bound to something?  Your *other* problem is that your app is leaking.

Comment: Yes, I set its data source to a DataTable, contents are loaded from db. Sorry, but what do you mean by that 'app is leaking'?

Comment: Will the images change from edits?  For instance if the user changes a row from Active to Inactive, will one change or are they static?  (it *may* be leaking, but it is consuming more resources than it needs to).

Comment: They are static. When the data is loaded, they are shown or hidden, and it stays that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using some unbound `DataGridViewImageColumn` and as mentioned in documents, The [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.image(v=vs.110).aspx) property specifies an image that is displayed in cells with no values when the column is not data-bound.

So by setting a cell value to null, you are forcing the cell to show the `Image` property.

To solve the problem:

1. For your columns set `column.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = Nothing`
2. Don't set the `Image` property.
3. Each time you want to show the image, assign the image to `Value` property of cell.

You can set value of Cell manually in a loop or using `CellFormatting` event. For example:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    If (e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = 2) Then 
        If (e.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0) Then 'Use any criteria which you need, it's a test
            e.Value = My.Resources.Image1
        Else
            e.Value = DBNull.Value
            e.CellStyle.NullValue = Nothing
        End If
    End If

   ' Do the same for other image columns. 

End Sub
```